# Trying to get a picker{} to show in SmartFace App Studio

Tags: ios, picker, smartface.io

I have been using the example code from SmartFace.io to work as follows:

```
    pick(
    myCars,
    selectedIndex,
    function(e) {Pages.NewPage.Label1.text = myCars[e.index]; selectedIndex = e.index; },
    function() {},
    function() {}
 );
```

However the picker just doesn't want to show in the emulator.  I have also tryied putting this code in a sepparate function and call it from a OnPress event of an ImageButton but still nothing.

I am trying this on an iPhone 4S so maybe that is the issue...

Any hint on what I am doing incorrectly would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Gerry

Comment: I should mention I have set up the variables for myCars and selected Index as  var myCars = ["Audi", "Volvo", "Volkswagon"] and var selectedIndex = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add a TextButton and Label to Page1 and write these codeLines. and it works; Maybe, some other codes breaks the functions.

```
var myCars = ["Audi", "Volvo", "Volkswagon"]; 
var selectedIndex = 0;

/**
* Creates action(s) that are run when the user press the key of the devices.
* @param {KeyCodeEventArguments} e Uses to for key code argument. It returns e.keyCode parameter.
* @this SMF.UI.Page
*/
function Page1_Self_OnKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 4) {
        Application.exit();
    }
}
/**
* Creates action(s) that are run when the page is appeared
* @param {EventArguments} e Returns some attributes about the specified functions
* @this SMF.UI.Page
*/
function Page1_Self_OnShow() {
    //Comment following block for removing navigationbar/actionbar sample
    //Copy this code block to every page onShow
    header.init(this);
    header.setTitle("Page1");
    header.setRightItem("RItem");
    header.setLeftItem();
    /**/
}
/**
* Creates action(s) that are run when the object is pressed from device's screen.
* @param {EventArguments} e Returns some attributes about the specified functions
* @this SMF.UI.TextButton
*/
function Page1_TextButton1_OnPressed(e){
      pick(
    myCars,
    selectedIndex,
    function(e) {Pages.NewPage.Label1.text = myCars[e.index]; selectedIndex = e.index; },
    function() {},
    function() {}
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  There must have been something in my code that was breaking it but it didn't throw an error.  Anyway, it works now... thanks for the help